# Splash screen & InApp purchases not working on a live app

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, store, splash-screen

I have recently published an App to the App store.

When testing the app everything was fine (in-app purchases, splash screens etc.).
Now that the app is live I have two major problems:

1. The splash screen (Default.png) is not showing. I have retested it on my development build and it 
   works fine but in the live app it is not working.
2. The in-app purchases are not working. I have retested it on my development build in sandbox and they 
   work fine but in the live app they are not working.

I have read that it is possible for in-app purchases not work for up to 36 hours after release but I have never had a problem where the Default.png file did not show.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Is it possible that I am meant to do something specific for the in-app purchases in when the app goes live ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While verification of transaction receipt check the url that u have used (This may be the case).

For an application which is going live: https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

For testing purpose: https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt.

Also check if the AppID that you have used while submitting the binary is Enabled for IAP.